# How can I reliably avoid missiles?

Tags: futuridium-ep

I always start to do poorly once I get put up against missiles.  I can never seem to shake them, and (particularly when trying to turn around) they almost always get me.

[image: These sons of bitches right here]

They go slightly faster than I do, and I sometimes have success weaving among obstacles because presumably they crash into them.

[image: SHIT]

Even this doesn't always work though, and there's not always obstacles to weave around anyway.  The undersides of the fleet ships, for example, are usually particularly bare.

[image: It was full while it lasted]

Poop.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am one of the developers of Futuridium!

You can avoid missiles in two ways:

1) fly in diagonal and you can go slightly faster than them, they can't hit you!
2) fly in diagonal or up/down and then turn, you'll avoid them. ;)

Hope you're enjoying the game! :)

Mauro

Comment: Woah! Developer answer! You're one cool dude.

Comment: @MauroFanelli Thanks for taking the time to respond!  I did notice that I seemed to last longer when I flew diagonally a lot, but I didn't realize it enabled me to outrun them!  I'm away this weekend but I'll give it a shot when I get home.  This game is great!  Very reminiscent of Starfox for me, and with a totally bitchin' soundtrack. =]